# SharePoint 2013 Site Definition Template Missing

Tags: visual-studio, site, site-definition, 2013

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate RC, and I did install the Sharepoint 2013 tools.
But cant find the site definition templates. Any thoughts??

Comment: You mean Visual Studio 2012 right?

Comment: yes Diptarag. Corrected

Comment: Its a project item now ..

Answer (score 4):

With the SharePoint 2013 tools they removed the Site Definition project template, but added Site Definition as a project item.

So you have to create an empty SharePoint 2013 Project and the add a new item of type Site Definition

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what steps you followed, please look at this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231583.aspx) instruction and check if you are doing it right.

Comment: This isn't valid when SharePoint 2013 tools are installed